# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode string read from pyvisa device

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

So I am using pyvisa to let python talk to some instrument. I have the code like this:

```
    self.receiver.write("mmem:data? \'traceData.DAT\'")
    sleep(2)
    data_string = self.receiver_visa.read()
```

The write part is to tell the instrument where to find the data, and wait 2 sec for it to find it, and then using read() to actually read that data. The data should look something like this:

```
'#525817Type;ESU;\r\nVersion;4.73;\r\nDate;10.May 17;\r\nMode;ANALYZER;\r\nCenter Freq;13560000.000000;Hz\r\nFreq Offset;0.000000;Hz\r\nSpan;1000000.000000;Hz\r\nx-Axis;LIN;\r\nStart;13060000.000000;Hz\r\nStop;14060000.000000;Hz\r\nRef Level;-36.000000;dBm\r\nLevel Offset;0.000000;dB\r\nRef Position;100.000000;%\r\ny-Axis;LOG;\r\nLevel Range;100.000000;dB\r\nRf Att;10.000000;dB\r\nRBW;10000.000000;Hz\r\nVBW;30000.000000;Hz\r\nSWT;0.040000;s\r\nTrace Mode;CLR/WRITE;\r\nDetector;MAXPEAK;\r\nSweep Count;0;\r\nTrace 1:;;\r\nx-Unit;Hz;\r\ny-Unit;dBm;\r\nPreamplifier;NOT AVAILABLE;\r\nTransducer;OFF;\r\nValues;625;\r\n13060000;-101.74840545654297;\r\n13061602.564102564;-102.10520935058594;\r\n13063205.128205128;-105.79591369628906;\r\n13064807.692307692;-111.44921875;\r\n13066410.256410256;-106.73763275146484;\r\n13068012.82051282;-105.97975158691406;\r\n13069615.384615384;-103.39719390869....
```

But when I run this code, I got a error message saying that

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position
>   243: ordinal not in range(128)

so I think the problem is about python not using utf-8. I tried to put

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

on the source code header, but this is not helping. I did a bit research and some suggests doing string.decode('utf-8'), but this won't work for me given I am reading from pyvisa device directly. Could someone please help?

TIA

Attached is full traceback:

```
>>> import pyvisa
>>> rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
>>> rm.list_resources()
('TCPIP0::178.168.48.147::inst0::INSTR', 'TCPIP0::178.168.48.21::inst0::INSTR', 'TCPIP0::178.168.48.30::inst0::INSTR', 'ASRL10::INSTR', 'GPIB0::5::INSTR', 'GPIB0::20::INSTR')
>>> maturo = rm.open_resource('GPIB0::20::INSTR')
>>> esu = rm.open_resource('GPIB0::20::INSTR')
>>> esu.query("*IDN?")
'Rohde&Schwarz,ESU-40,100348/040,4.73\n'
>>> esu.write("mmem:del \'traceData.DAT\'")
(26, <StatusCode.success: 0>)
>>> esu.write("mmem:cdir \'D:\'")
(16, <StatusCode.success: 0>)
>>> esu.write("hcop:dev:lang DAT")
(19, <StatusCode.success: 0>)
>>> esu.write("hcop:dest \'mmem\'")
(18, <StatusCode.success: 0>)
>>> esu.write("mmem:stor:trac 1,\'traceData.DAT\'")
(34, <StatusCode.success: 0>)
>>> esu.write("mmem:data? \'traceData.DAT\'")
(28, <StatusCode.success: 0>)
>>> esu.read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    esu.read()
  File "C:\Users\hansong.li\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\resources\messagebased.py", line 332, in read
    message = self.read_raw().decode(enco)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 241: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: You'll need to include the *full traceback* of that exception, so we can properly assess what is causing this.

Comment: And no, the source code encoding is *not* going to be the cause. That only affects how string literals are decoded, not data read from elsewhere.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for your response. I put the traceback now. But I don't think that is largely helpful...

Comment: On the contrary, I find it helpful. I see that the `.read()` method has a `encoding` argument. Do you know what kind of data is being returned? You could use `esu.read(encoding='latin1')`, that'll make the error go away but it could lead to a [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh wow that worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. Would you mind presenting it as an answer so that I could set it as accepted answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to specify an encoding when reading. The [`MessageBasedResource.read()` method](http://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/resources.html#pyvisa.resources.MessageBasedResource.read) takes an `encoding` parameter:

```
ng = self.receiver_visa.read(encoding='latin1')
```

You'll need to either figure out what encoding the instrument uses, *or* use the [`MessageBasedResource.read_raw()` method](http://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/resources.html#pyvisa.resources.MessageBasedResource.read_raw) to read binary data instead.

Watch out, using the wrong codec could lead to a [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake); Latin-1 in particular will always happily decode any binary data, but the resulting text may not be legible.